# last reboot command shows strange behavior (or maybe im wrong)

Tags: reboot, last

In last reboot command normally if im not wrong it shows the last reboot time and n-2 reboot time but as you can see in below image it is showing same time for last 4 reboots

```
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1160.24.1 Thu Apr 29 21:09 - 11:51 (2+14:42)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1160.24.1 Thu Apr 29 16:49 - 11:51 (2+19:02)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1127.8.2. Thu Apr 29 15:22 - 11:51 (2+20:28)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1127.8.2. Thu Feb 11 18:57 - 11:51 (79+16:54)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1127.8.2. Thu Feb 11 18:47 - 18:54  (00:07)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1127.8.2. Fri Dec 11 10:12 - 15:36 (62+05:23)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1127.8.2. Fri Oct 30 08:25 - 10:09 (42+01:43)

wtmp begins Mon Apr 13 14:26:21 2020
```

OS = RHEL 7.6 Two Node Clustered using Pacemaker

[image]

Comment: OS = RHEL 7.6 Two Node Clustered using Pacemaker